# How do I get Intellij to follow the cursor right when I move off the screen?

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

If I press `l` to go off the screen to the right, IdeaVim doesn't scroll the window with it.  As a result, I can't see where my cursor is.  I tested this with regular Vim and it doesn't act this way: It brings the window with it if you move off the window.  How can I make IdeaVim act this way?

I am using Intellij 14.0.3 and the latest IdeaVim on a Mac.

Comment: Did you try their issue tracker?

Comment: I've never encountered this problem. Which version of IDEA are you using? And have you updated IdeaVim plugin?

Comment: Your bug report is welcome here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM Do you experience this all the time with files of any type? I cannot reproduce the problem with IntelliJ 14.1 and IdeaVim 0.39.